# [screen is terminating], but never terminates

Tags: games, screen, minecraft

I recently ran into an issue on my Ubuntu 12.10 server that I can't seem to find a solution for. From my server I run a couple of Minecraft servers on different ports, usually to start the servers I would use the following command.

```
screen -S minecraft java -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

There was never a problem until recently, as soon as I run the command it outputs

```
[screen is terminating]
```

No matter what privileges/account I'm under, sudo, root, a normal user, none of them. All return the same thing. I've tried rebooting the entire server, wiping all screens `screen -wipe`. I've also tried listing all the screens thinking that it would expose the screen that is still "terminating", but all it returns is `No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user.`

What else can I do?

Comment: Are you sure this is a screen problem? Did you try running just the java command from a normal terminal (`java -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui`)? If that works, the problem is probably screen. But if it doesn't, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
killall screen
```

This will kill all instances of it. Also be sure to try rebooting if you haven't already. It also could be java. You might try killing that too.